# openoffice calc. There is another way to do sumif?

Tags: openoffice-calc

How could you do this differently. shorter ?
=SUM(IF(G52>F52))+SUM(IF(H52>G52))+SUM(IF(I52>H52))+SUM(IF(J52>I52))+SUM(IF(K52>J52))+SUM(IF(L52>K52))

Comment: Perhaps it would help to provide a description of what this is intended to accomplish.  Is it used for sorting perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

This formula produces the same results:

```
=(G52>F52)+(H52>G52)+(I52>H52)+(J52>I52)+(K52>J52)+(L52>K52)
```

Comment: Thanks, what I want is to cover a range..ej g52: k52 ..is better than I thought

Answer (score 0):

I think this also produces the same result:

```
=SUM(G52:L52>F52:K52)
```

entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter